# Theodicy in the Or Zarua

Tags: sources-mekorot, theodicy

I remember reading that the Or Zarua attributed the suffering of Jews in Hungary and other lands in eastern Europe to the fact that they were studying insufficient Torah. I can no longer find a source for this, nor locate the idea in the Or Zarua itself. If anybody is familiar with Sefer Or Zarua and knows of the passage to which I am referring, please let me know where I can find it. I had thought that it was in one of the teshuves found at the end of the second volume, but does not appear to be.

Comment: Theodicy is (very roughly) "bad things happening to good people." This argument, if it was said, is to say that it's not really theodicy, because those people aren't "good." (Just nitpicking on the language.) Not unlike what Iyov's friends attempt ...

Comment: @Shalom - The word theodicy means “divine justice”. It is also why and how bad things happen to people who are not good.

Comment: I did not know that -- thank you!